# Walking to Idle animation transition trouble

Tags: c#, xna

I'm having trouble transitioning my walking to idle animations.

Maybe there's a better way to go about this?

**The problem**: I can check for NO key presses on the keyboard, but it causes the walking animation to display only the first frame and not the full animation.

**The question:** How can I change this so that when the user is done walking, it will change the state back to "Idle" without conflicting with the animations of walking left and right.

```
   private void UpdateMovement(KeyboardState aCurrentKeyboardState, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        timeSinceLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds; //Framerate control

        if (timeSinceLastFrame > millisecondsPerFrame) //Framerate control
        {
            timeSinceLastFrame -= millisecondsPerFrame; //Framerate control

            //Idle if no keys are down
            if (mCurrentState == State.Idle)
            {
                Position.Y = 210;
                currentImageIndex++;
                if (currentImageIndex < 17 || currentImageIndex > 23)
                    currentImageIndex = 17;
            }
                //Walk Left
            if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                    mCurrentState = State.Walking;
                    if (currentImageIndex < 8 || currentImageIndex > 15)
                        currentImageIndex = 8;   
                    Position.Y = 200;
                    currentImageIndex++;
                    Position.X += MOVE_LEFT;
                    if (currentImageIndex > 15)
                        currentImageIndex = 8;
            }
                //Walk Right
                if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
                {
                    mCurrentState = State.Walking;
                    if (currentImageIndex > 7)
                        currentImageIndex = 0;
                    Position.Y = 200; ;
                    currentImageIndex++;
                    Position.X += MOVE_RIGHT;
                    if (currentImageIndex > 7)
                        currentImageIndex = 0;
                }
            if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.None))
                mCurrentState = State.Idle;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Keys.None` is not semantically equivalent to "no keys are pressed", it is rather just a reserved value by the operating system. See for instance the [documentation for the Keys enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keys.aspx). Therefore, I doubt this code will lead your character back to `State.Idle` after having reached `State.Walking`, the animation will just stop when you release the keys. To check whether no keys are pressed alter the last `if` statement to use `aCurrentKeyboardState.GetPressedKeys().Length == 0` instead, or swap with an `else` statement which then would be reached when neither of `Keys.Left` or `Keys.Right` are pressed.

Comment: Thank you get much. I had actually done this before and taken it away due to a looping problem in one of my attack methods. However, I was reminded of something I forgot about. Thanks again!